# Syntax error with placeholder in python with sqlite INSERT command

Tags: python, syntax, sqlite, arguments

I am getting an error with the second placeholder on MySQL query:

```
photo_number_value = c.execute('INSERT into ebay VALUES (?,?)', photo_number_key,photo_number)
```

the error that I'm getting is:

> unexpected argument

Answer (score 3):

Syntax errors and "unexpected argument" errors are different things. But since `execute` only takes two parameters, I'll go with the latter. You need to put the parameter values into a list or tuple to make it work:

```
photo_number_value = c.execute('INSERT into ebay VALUES (?,?)',
    (photo_number_key,photo_number))
```